# BouncyCastle on GAE/J

Tags: google-app-engine, bouncycastle

According to this Issue on Google Code for GAE, BouncyCastle should just work fine.
Can anyone confirm this? Because I can't get it to run...

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1612#c18

Comment: what is the problem you are having?

Comment: Adding a provider throw a java.security.AccessControlException.

Comment: Yay, found a solution: Using the latest GAE SDK 1.7.2, i can add any provider i want (previously i was on 1.6).

Answer (score 1):

[Cumulus4j](http://cumulus4j.org/latest-stable/) apparently runs fine on GAE/J and it uses BouncyCastle. Not used it, but the people behind that software have in their testing